# Sample size needed for a given difference of sample means for a Skewed normal distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

The vertical coordinate (in pixels from top to bottom) of human eye position when viewing faces is found to be a right skewed distribution. I computed the fit for 125 observers using MATLABs Epsilon Skewed Normal.
EpsilonSkewNormal distribution

```
  theta =   473.183   [453.855, 492.51]
  sigma =   43.9546   [-442.878, 530.787]
epsilon = -0.281684   [-0.535551, -0.0278181]
```

The Kolmogrov Smirnov test shows a non significant P value of 0.34, skewness of the data is ~0.70.

I want to sample 2 groups of 16 observers for a research project such that the distance between the means of these samples is atleast 240 pixels. I want to find out how many observers I need to find these groups (power analysis)

I tried fitting a simple normal distribution to the data and got
Normal distribution

```
mu = 491.866   [483.696, 500.035]
sigma = 45.3858   [40.2984, 51.9551]
```

Based on this I computed the difference distribution to be Normal with

$$\mu_{difference} = 0$$ $$\sigma_{difference} = \sqrt\frac{2\sigma^2}{16} = 16.04 $$

From this distribution when I tried 1-normcdf(240,0,$\sigma_{difference}$) it is ~$10^{-54}$! Does this mean it is literally impossible to find such samples? Would this number be higher if I consider the skewness? I imagine that my chances of finding such groups increases with skewness (with the unskewed normal distribution having the lowest probability). If yes, how do I go about estimating my actual chances here? Finally, assuming that I have the resources (time,money and energy) to collect around 250 observers, how can I calculate the maximum difference between 16 sample groups I can expect to find, with say 80% probability?

Any help is appreciated!